# Unit Test: Assert range of a list with greater or lesser than

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing

I'm using  Microsoft unit test framework and want to check if a list contains elements that are greater or lesser than a specific number.

I know it's possible when using an int data-type, but how can I do that with a list?

**EDIT**

```
    Assert.IsTrue( myCollection.Any(a => a > min)); \\ helped me
```

++

Use "All" if you want to make sure that EVERY element is greater or less:

```
    Assert.IsTrue( myCollection.All(a => a > min && a < max));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(myCollection.Any(a => a > min));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CollectionAssert class rather than Assert:

```
CollectionAssert.Contains(list, element);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243705.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I tried that, but how can I check the range? Like: CollectionAssert.Contains(list, > 1020 && < 2100)

Comment: See Asad's answer. That is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it contains an element greater that 100 you can write

```
Assert.IsTrue(list.Where(x => x > 100).Any());
```

Comment: You don't really need a separate `Where` here.